# How to access the current state of an option within a tkinter widget?

Tags: tkinter

Say I define a button as

```
button = tk.Button(window, width=20 ...)
```

How can I view an options (e.g. 'width') current value, so that the output is

```
20
```

Answer (score 0):

widgetname['option'], i.e.

```
button['bg']
```